# Compile Unreal Lightmass. Error with Unreal 4.24 build from source on Linux

Tags: unreal-engine4

I get the following error when I am trying to build a project in Unreal, that I have included some lightning. "Lighting Build Failed. Swarm failed to Kick off. Compile Unreal Lightmass".

I have build Unreal Engine 4.24.1 from source on Linux with the setup instructions from the documentations.

Any ideas how to proceed. How would I go and compile Unreal Lightmass for the Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some sparse search here and there, I was able to solve this.
To compile the UnrealLightmass there is a build shell script in the directory

```
UnrealEngine_Repo_dir/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux
```

You need to run the `./Build.sh` with the following input

```
./UnrealEngine_Repo_dir/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/Build.sh UnrealLightmass Linux Development -verbose
```

This should start compilation and build the UnrealLightmass. 
This probably is the way to build the remaining programs that the Unreal Engine would complain that you haven't build.
Any program that is under the directory

```
/UnrealEngine_Repo_dir/Engine/Source/Programs
```

can be build with the above command. One example would be the ShaderCompileWorker.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you did the full source build setup process, Lightmass should have compiled as well. Here is a probably-foolproof solution:

1. Run Setup.sh
2. Run GenerateProjectFiles.sh
3. Once the Visual Studio .sln is finished generating, open that.
4. Wait for the option to appear, then (Toolbar) Build->Build Solution

The UEBuildTool should then compile everything in the project, including Lightmass.

Comment: I run the Setup and GenerateProjectFiles shell scripts. Then running make build everything else and the engines runs ok. I dont have VS IDE on Linux since its not supported. Any other solution?

Comment: @bad_locality you can directly call the build tool from command line, assuming you have the library prerequisites installed. I’ll look up what file that is...

Comment: @bad_locality It should be an executable called UnrealBuildTool. I’m not sure about command line options to send it yet.

Comment: Yes the UnrealBuildTool.csproj exists in the Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool directory. Is there some way I can use this with Mono IDE to build the  Unreal LightMass?

Comment: @bad_locality UnrealBuildTool itself is compiled using the info in that .csproj, I think. I think you’re looking for a binary executable.

Comment: ok I have found the Build.sh script that it is supposed to build the Programs. I successfully managed to build the UnrealLightmass. It was a bit tricky though and there are not that many resources/docs out there for this. I will post an answer shortly